# Why do I get Compile Errors of x64 Application,when the application runs successfully

Tags: vb.net, 64-bit

I have x64 vb.net solution which shows compile errors (unrecognised namespaces, types) but then it runs successfully with the supposedly problematic namespaces and types.  The solution has recently been changed from x86 architecture.  I have never had this situation arise before, normally when a solution fails to compile it also fails to run in the development envronment.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Clean the solution prior to compiling.

Comment: When you get the message about compile errors, which button do you click? Code that won't compile won't run.

Comment: I attempt to compile the entire solution, and it generates a compile error.  However if I run the application from the Debug toolbar it works.

Comment: Default behavior is to run the last-good build of a project.  Easy to fix with Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > "On Run, when build or deployment error occurs" = Do not launch.

Answer (score 0):

sorted the issue, for some reason the dependencies in the solution had gotten 'knocked out of whack'.  Dependencies sorted, which appears to have resolved the issue, I'm still a bit perplexed as to how it would run in debug mode, but not compile but don't need to dwell on the issue, just happy that I can get back to productive work on this application.

Thanks for your feedback.